# How to inject bean in controller without annotation in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-ioc

I am developing spring mvc web application. I want to inject a bean class inside controller or service class but I don't want to use any type of annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Define you bean in your appContext.xml or your bean config file

```
<bean id="mybean" class="MyClass"></bean>
```

And call your bean inside your controller using ApplicationContext interface :

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("appContext.xml");

MyClass mybean= applicationContext.getBean("mybean");
```

Comment: Suppose that I have to use same bean in other class also. again i have to call application context interface reference. i think its not good idea for web application. its ok for standalone apllication so please tell other solution.